# How to make grid of divs ignore eachother

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a grid of divs that I am removing with jquery's remove function. When one div is removed, the rest move. Is there a way to keep the grid's shape, and have the divs stay in place upon removal? Thanks.

LINK - https://jsfiddle.net/n4y6sfg6/7/

```
.boards{
    height:630px;
    width:630px;
    background-color:orange;
    border-radius:5px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-315px;
    position:relative;
}
.row{
    width:100%;
    height:157.5px;
}

.cards{
    width:120px;
        height:125px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:16px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color:grey;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n4y6sfg6/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove them, instead set `visibility: hidden;`

https://jsfiddle.net/n4y6sfg6/14/

Comment: Does visibility have none value?

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove div.You can add a class to the div that you want to hide.For example

`<div class="cards remove-card"></div>`

then style the class like

```
.remove-card{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use jQuery, you could use the opacity function.

```
$("#element").opacity(0);
```

This will leave the element exactly where it is, but invisible.